# Align textview columns vertically when using custom adaptor / layoutinflator

Tags: android, textview, alignment

I have three columns that I want to align vertically. The data for the columns are retrieved using an object and then displayed using a `LayoutInflater.`

At present the columns are all over the place. I am hoping to have them perfectly aligned. I'm using `TextView` but I am starting to wonder if I shouldn't be using some kind of `TableLayout.`

[image]
Here is the XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/table_layout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <TableRow android:id="@+id/row_multi_row">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/item1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:padding="3dip"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/item2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:padding="3dip"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/item3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:padding="3dip"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

Comment: your text views are not set to `fill_parent`, so they will only ever take as much room as they need.

Answer (score 1):

[image]Try this :

```
<TableRow xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/row_multi_row"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:weightSum="1">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/item1"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="0.34"
    android:padding="3dip"
    android:text="asdasd"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/item2"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="0.34"
    android:padding="3dip"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="adasd"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/item3"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="0.32"
    android:padding="3dip"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="asdasdad"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
```

Answer (score 0):

set all textview width and tab row width to fill parent and use layout_weight="1". It will work